# Run for final Hot Tub Connection

Tags: electrical, hot-tub

I have a hot tub I need to relocate.  Previously it was a flexible liquidtight whip that ran from the breaker panel directly into the hot tub through one of the access ports.   With the move I'd like to bury the line to the hot tub.  I am planning to use metal conduit from the panel into the ground, then rigid pvc underground.  What I'm not sure about is the combination of fittings I should use to make the final run into the hot tub.

I have included a picture of the hot tub with the access port circled.  [image: Hot Tub with access port]

I need to pass about 10 ft of flexible liquidtight into the hot tub to make the final connections.  Should I transition from rigid PVC in the ground to metal above ground, finally connecting to the flexible liquidtight or is there a better combination. Is it okay to go rigid pvc to the flexible liquidtight at the top (without metal conduit). Finally what fitting would be best to make the 90 degree transition?  Thanks and let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 4):

### PVC to liquidtight works, but with a caveat or two

The good news is that it's possible to transition from a PVC conduit to liquidtight flexible conduit without too much work.  However, you can only do it from a *spigot* (male) end.  This primarily means you can't use a LB to make the 90° bend at the hot tub end without having to use a nipple of PVC to adapt the liquidtight fitting to the *hub* on the conduit body atop the parts you'd normally use.

In particular, you need to use a PVC *female adapter* fitting to transition from the unthreaded spigot end of conduit coming out of the ground to female threads you can then thread a LFNC ("Carflex") connector into, sans locknut of course.  Note that you *can* use a 90° LFNC connector here if the bend radius of the conduit itself is too wide to make the transition.

If you're using LFMC ("Sealtite"), you can do likewise as well, although that does come with its own caveat, namely that you'll need to make sure that the hot-tub end of the LFMC is bonded to ground correctly, which may require a bonding locknut on the LFMC fitting at that end of the connection.